# Build Tensorflow Lite for Android NDK/C++

Tags: android, tensorflow, cmake, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use Tensorflow Lite in a purely native C++/NDK Android app.

How do I build Tensorflow Lite for NDK/C++?
I want to integrate the library using CMake and don't need any Java parts.